# How to create custom enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\bulletlabel}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\small$\bullet$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\bulletlabel, topsep=0pt, leftmargin=0.3in, rightmargin=0.3in]
    \item One
    \item Two
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I've parameterised my enumerate environment to get the formatting I want. I use this set of parameters fairly often in my document, together with 2 other sets of parameters.

Is there a quick way for me to replicate this without having to copy/paste or type it out every time? I don't want to redefine the default enumerate environment, as there are 2 other sets of parameters that I need to handle as well. I'm just looking for a quick way to do it.

I tried this:

```
\newcommand{\paramone}{label=\bulletlabel, topsep=0pt, leftmargin=0.3in, rightmargin=0.3in}
```

But when I use:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\paramone]
```

It fails because it processes it as one parameter rather than 4.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: These are expansion issues, I think. You could make it work using `\newcommand{\paramone}{label=\noexpand\bulletlabel, topsep=0pt, leftmargin=0.3in, rightmargin=0.3in}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{enumerate}[\paramone]}
\temp
    \item One
    \item Two
\end{enumerate} ` Of course this is not necessarily elegant. (I am also surprised to see how quickly this got closed, and am not convinced that the correct "partner" post has been identified.)

Comment: @marmot I have made it work using `\newlist{intextbullets}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[intextbullets]{label=\bulletlabel, topsep=0pt, leftmargin=0.3in, rightmargin=0.3in}`.

Comment: I think my first comment identifies the correct post to refer to, rather than the one it was marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: Yes, your way more elegant and I did not close your question.